# How to make QChart widget thinner than 180p

Tags: qt

It seems that QChart has a minimum height of 180px. I want a thin plot. I've even removed margins/titles/labels and etc, but not able to make it thinner that 180px.
How can I do that?
Regards,

Comment: Call `setMinimumHeight` and see if that does it.

Comment: Yeah, That worked!!! Thanks